# get latest directory contents in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

I just started using IntelliJ and I wanted to know what is the best way to replace your workspace directory contents with the latest ones from cvs. Whenever I run update it doesn't overwrite the changes I made but I am looking for an option where it will blindly overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a `force checkout` or `force update`, this isn't really an Intellij IDEA issue, as much as it is a CVS behavior regardless of IDE, or no IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Changes view, revert all of your local changes from there, and then update from the version control.